# How to disable certificate caching in https.get call of node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have following node.js code to get the certificates and other details of the server. But it's getting the certificate only in the first call of `https.get`.
Successive calls are not fetching the certificates from the server.

```
var https = require('https');
var i = 0;
test();

function test() {
    var request = https.get("https://google.com", function (result) {
        console.log(result.statusCode)
        var cert = result.connection.getPeerCertificate(true);
        console.log("Certificate is", cert)
        i++;
        if (i < 10)
            test();
    }).on('error', function (err) {
        console.log("error is", err);
    })
}
```

So I feel Node.js will cache the server certificate received.

If that's the case, then how can I clear the certificates present in the memory.

If not, then what is the reason for this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default [`https.Agent`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_class_https_agent) caches (at most) 100 TLS sessions.

You can disable the agent for your requests, so the sessions aren't cached:

```
const url = require('url');
...
function test() {
  let opts   = url.parse('https://google.com');
  opts.agent = false;

  var request = https.get(opts, ...);
}
```